# How can I find unsupported / deprecated jQuery functions in a JS file?

Tags: jquery, deprecated

Is there a website or a tool where I can enter some jQuery code and it will show me whether unsupported / deprecated functions are used in this code?

This would be really nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery now provide a migrate plugin (1.4.1 & 3.0+) to display warnings on any use of deprecated functions in browser console:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Answer (score 4):

jQuery lint should do the job:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/

Comment: Looks like jQuery-lint is no longer under active development, plus it only supports a few (old) versions of jQuery. Is there anything else out there that will check code for deprecated jQuery?